# Listener only adds last image in list to the RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I get a Data snapshot of the user's ids. These ids are also the same as the image ids of the matching profile pictures of the users.
I want to populate the RecyclerView with each image that matches the RecyclerView, but what happens is, that it populate the correct user id, but it only populates the last image in the list of the data snapshot instead of all. So I end up with a list of user ids and a single image at the bottom:

```
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                imageName = ds.getKey();                   
                user = new User(imageName);
                myDataset.add(user);

                storageReference.child("profileImages").child(imageName).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {


                        user.setImageUri(uri);
                        // Got the download URL                            
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle any errors                            
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    imagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Only one image]

This is the adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<User> mDataset;
    private MyViewHolder myHolder;
    private User user;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView userIdTextView;
        public ImageView userProfileImageView;
        public View layout;
        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            layout = v;
            userProfileImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);

        public TextView userIdTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_id_text_view);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<User> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {


        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        myHolder = holder;
        user = mDataset.get(position);
        Uri userImage = user.getImageUri();
        myHolder.userIdTextView.setText(user.getUsername());

        Glide.with(myHolder.itemView.getContext() /* context */)
                .load(userImage)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(300, 300))
                .into(myHolder.userProfileImageView);


    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

database structure:

```
database
   |_____users
           |___uid1 
           |___uid2
           |___uid3
```

Comment: Provide your adapter code, so we can idea

Comment: Please add your database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo added database structure and adapter. The problem is not with the database structure, because I get the correct user names (I checked initially with Logging)

Comment: @sStacker Why are you not storing directly the image url rather than the image name?

Answer (score 1):

Your "user" variable cannot be used in that way inside "onSuccess()" callback method. That variable refers always to the LAST "new User()", so when the "download" procedure reach the "onSuccess()" the value of "user" value is THE LATEST executed "new User()". You need to pass something like an "userID" to the download method and when the "onSuccess()" is executed you have to find the right User using that ID, and then set its image.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, Where do I start

Comment: by the way, the user id is the same as `imageName`, so what can I do from here?

Answer (score 0):

As **getDownloadUrl** is async method other user objects are changed and only last object is referenced when **onSuccess()** is called so last objects uri is set.

1. Use `HashMap<String,User> userMap = new HashMap<String,User>();`
2. Before **getDownloadUrl**

   `userMap.put(imageName,user);`
3. in **onSuccess()**

   `User user = userMap.get(imageName);
   user.setImageUri(uri);`

Make imageName final.

Comment: I don't understand where to place each in my code, can you please help me more? I just can't understand where I need to use it. Also, how can imageName be final if it always changes?